# Populate a column in SharePoint

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, datasheet

I have 2 Different SharePoint installations. The new one is missing a column from when I used a tool to migrate.

Now if I use the datasheet and export the missing column and its values to excel why cant I then import it back to my new list in the empty column?

Comment: Is it a lookup column?

Comment: what error you are getting? you just trying to import the value?

Comment: no it is an ordinary column. and the error is that I am out of bounds.